# Calling a function from injected pagescript in Mozilla Addon SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to inject a function into a webpage and call it, however no matter how I try it, whenever I try to call the function I get that it's undefined. I understand the browser reads function definitions on the page load and won't do so afterward, but is there a way for me to insert my functions in time. Here's a junk function I'd like to insert:

```
function makeAlert(word){
    alert(word);
}
```

I've tried to inject it as is, append it to the body with `<script>` tags, and append it using `<script src="makeAlert.js"></script>` into the head with page-mod. However whatever I do, if I try to call the function on the page (using injected content script), the function is marked as undefined. Here is the basic code of what I thought would work:

in main.js

```
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptFile: self.data.url("makeAlert.js")
  });
```

edit: as what I want to do seems to not be possible, my simple question is--Can I call a function I wrote from injected pagescript?

Answer (score 0):

Content scripts are kept (mostly) separate from the web page for security reasons, see

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts

If you really want to do this, you can by instead doing:

```
unsafeWindow.makeAlert = function (word){
    alert(word);
}
```

A couple of important things about doing things this way:

1. unsafeWindow is, well, UNSAFE. Never trust any data that come from unsafeWindow, ever.
2. it will go away some time this year ( unsure of the exact timing )

What you should probably do instead is using postMessage from the web page to the content script to pass mesages. For more on how to do this safely, please read these docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Communicating_With_Other_Scripts#Page_Scripts

Comment: I know about post message, but what I want to do is embed a function in the pagescript that is called from the same pagescript: for example, injecting something like: `<a onmouseover="anInjectedFunction()">` and having that be able to find `anInjectedFunction()`

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to do that, it's a security footgun. What if another script on the page redefines your function after you create it to do something bad?

Comment: I always assumed my function would be the one with a limited chance of overwriting the page's function, not the other way around. Perhaps I'm asking the wrong question though. I'll rephrase it to 'How do I call any function I wrote from injected pagescript'